# BufferedReader replacing in loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to make this work, I don't understand why it doesn't work since it makes sense to me, but it doesn't make sense to java it seems.

As you read the code, what I expect is _NAME to be replaced by TEST while maintaining the same structure of the text (keeping \n) to save it later(not done yet)

I also stored it using ArrayList, but the replace never took off either, so I'm clueless

```
    try {
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (
       new FileInputStream (temp), "utf-8"));
       String line = reader.readLine();
       StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();

    while(line != null) {
        line.replace("[_NAME]", "TEST");
        Logger.info(line);
        line = reader.readLine();

        }
    reader.close();


    } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {

    } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {

    } catch(IOException ex ) {}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct line is

```
line = line.replace("_NAME", "TEST");
```

If you use brackets, you are specifying the characters as individual matches (`_`, `N`, `A`, `M` and `E`), and you want to replace the whole match.

Second, the `replace` method return a new String that contains the modified String. Remember that Strings in Java are immutable, so no method that modifies a String would modify the input object, they will always return a new object.

Comment: At last! I still got it working with brackets, I thought the brackets would be in `replaceAll` only... (are you referring to the subpattern?)

Comment: @allenskd Subpattern? I guess you are a bit confused about regexes. I suggest you to read the javadocs ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html ). But the same rule applies to both `replace` and `replaceAll`, the only difference is that the former replaces just the first match. With your code, it would replace the first character among `_`, `N`, `A`, `M` or `E` with `TEST`.

Comment: It just came as a surprise I guess, well good to know to get better with Java, thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

One possible problem is the fact that you have `[]` around `_NAME` but I'm going to go with the "you forgot that `replace` returns the new string instead of changing it in-situ" option. See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29).

In other words, it should changed from:

```
line.replace ( ...
```

to:

```
line = line.replace ( ...
```